# Truncating miliseconds from Timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I'm trying to use TRUNC function to truncate milliseconds from Timestamp field.
In my table, timestamp is like this:

> 2022-06-01-14:22:37.965000

and I wanna get rid of milliseconds.

What I'm trying is this query:

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1 PT INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE2 ST
                        ON (ST.PROPERTY1 = PT.PROPERTY1 AND
                        ST.PROPERTY2 = PT.PROPERTY2 AND
                        ST.PROPERTY3 = PT.PROPERTY3 AND
                        ST.PROPERTY4 = PT.PROPERTY4 AND
                        ST.PROPERTY5 = PT.PROPERTY5 AND
                        ST.PROPERTY6 = PT.PROPERTY6  AND
                        ST.PROPERTY7 = PT.PROPERTY7 AND
                        ST.PROPERTY8 = PT.PROPERTY8)
                        WHERE ST.ID = 4 AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(ST.TIMESTAMP), SECOND) = '2022-06-01-14:22:37'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens - do you get an error, or not the result you expect? Is the value in your table a timestamp or a string? If it's a timestamp then don't use `to_date()` on it; but you could cast it as a date, which would lose the milliseconds - and then compare with another date, not a string. If it's a string then just `substr()` it; or use `to_timestamp()` not `to_date()`; or use `to_date()` on the substring - but supply the format model for either `to_*()` function.

Comment: I get error: "SECOND" is not valid in the context where it is used

Comment: Does it have to be `TRUNC`ated? Would it matter if it was rounded to the nearest second?

Comment: It has to be truncated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to round the `TIMESTAMP` to the nearest second then use:

```sql
CAST(ts AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

If you want to truncate the `TIMESTAMP` to the start of the current second then use:

```sql
CAST(
  TRUNC(ts, 'MI') + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts))
  AS TIMESTAMP(0)
)
```

or cast it to a date and then back to a timestamp:

```sql
CAST(CAST(ts AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

(with whatever precision you desire)

---

For example:

```
SELECT ts,
       CAST(ts AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS ts_rounded,
       CAST(
         TRUNC(ts, 'MI') + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts))
         AS TIMESTAMP(0)
       ) AS ts_trunc
FROM   (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-06-01 14:22:37.965000' AS ts
  FROM   DUAL
)
```

Outputs:

> | TS | TS_ROUNDED | TS_TRUNC |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-06-01 14:22:37.965000000 | 2022-06-01 14:22:38. | 2022-06-01 14:22:37. |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a008d81711890cda5a09287804bc127f)*

---

However, it may be simpler to either use a range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   SCHEMA.TABLE1 PT
       INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE2 ST
       ON (ST.PROPERTY1 = PT.PROPERTY1 AND
           ST.PROPERTY2 = PT.PROPERTY2 AND
           ST.PROPERTY3 = PT.PROPERTY3 AND
           ST.PROPERTY4 = PT.PROPERTY4 AND
           ST.PROPERTY5 = PT.PROPERTY5 AND
           ST.PROPERTY6 = PT.PROPERTY6  AND
           ST.PROPERTY7 = PT.PROPERTY7 AND
           ST.PROPERTY8 = PT.PROPERTY8)
WHERE  ST.ID = 4
AND    st.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP '2022-06-01 14:22:37'
AND    st.timestamp <  TIMESTAMP '2022-06-01 14:22:37' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
```

(Which would use an index on the `st.timestamp` column)

Or to convert the value to a string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   SCHEMA.TABLE1 PT
       INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE2 ST
       ON (ST.PROPERTY1 = PT.PROPERTY1 AND
           ST.PROPERTY2 = PT.PROPERTY2 AND
           ST.PROPERTY3 = PT.PROPERTY3 AND
           ST.PROPERTY4 = PT.PROPERTY4 AND
           ST.PROPERTY5 = PT.PROPERTY5 AND
           ST.PROPERTY6 = PT.PROPERTY6  AND
           ST.PROPERTY7 = PT.PROPERTY7 AND
           ST.PROPERTY8 = PT.PROPERTY8)
WHERE  ST.ID = 4
AND    TO_CHAR(st.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = '2022-06-01 14:22:37';
```

(Which would not use an index to `st.timestamp` and, instead, would require a separate function-based index on `TO_CHAR(st.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`.)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use TO_CHAR with the appropriate format to get your desired result:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(ST.TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS') = '2022-06-01-14:22:37'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to truncate to second precision is to cast to a date:

```
select cast(timestamp '2022-06-01 14:22:37.965' as date) from dual

2022-06-01 14:22:37
```

And then either compare that with another date, or cast back to a timestamp to compare with another timestamp. (Either way, don't compare with a string - only do that if you convert your timestamp value to a string as well, explicitly in the same format. And don't use `to_date()` on a date or timestamp value - you're relying on implicit conversion and your NLS settings.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=64db415623325aeeb885e4dd0641b303)